# How to schedule operation on background thread [Cocoa]

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

With Cocoa, how can I schedule an operation (block of code) to run asynchronously on a background thread?

There is a risk that the operation will block for a long time, so it is of critical importance that the operation is not executed on the main thread.

Of course, I can create my own thread (`NSThread`), but it seems to me that Cocoa should offer an easier/better way.

Comment: There are about 5 different ways to do this.

Comment: @HotLicks Good. Let me know about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Grand Central Dispatch command dispatch_async() to easily run code in the background. An example of this:

```
dispatch_queue_t bgQueue = dispatch_queue_create("bgQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(bgQueue, ^{
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the documentation does not say that this will run the block on a background thread, i.e., on a thread that is not the main thread. Am I missing something?

Comment: It will dispatch to whatever queue you set as the first parameter. Any queue you don't create using `dispatch_get_main_queue()` is not the main queue. Therefore your block will run in the background (e.g. not on the main queue).

Comment: @jshier Are you saying that the main thread will never execute stuff submitted to a GCD queue unless that queue is the main queue? Note that what is important here is not which queue that runs it, but which thread.

Comment: @jshier Ok, that sounds good. Do you know where the documentation says that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_main_queue

Returns the serial dispatch queue associated with the application’s main thread.

Comment: @jshier It is fairly obvious that the main queue is executed by the main thread. It is not obvious to me, however, that the main thread is never going to execute (or participate in executing) other queues. I suppose you believe that the latter is also the case.

Comment: @jshier The documentation, that you point to, only states that the main queue is executed by the main thread, and not that other queues are never executed by the main thread, right?

Comment: It's fairly obvious if you're at all familiar with GCD. If you're not, I'd suggest reading the GCD documentation and watching the various GCD WWDC session videos from the last 5 years.

Comment: @jshier Probably :-). I just hoped you could point me to the right place in the documentation.

Comment: @KristianSpangsege The types of queues are explained right at the beginning of the Concurrency Programming Guide: Dispatch Queues section. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1